# Facebook login from internal IOS webpage

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview

I load a webpage from native app's resource to UIWebview, and I want to login to facebook 
from that page. According to FB's [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication), I need redirect_uri which is not available for an internal page.

Is there anyway to login Facebook from an internal webpage?

lvreiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FBConnect SDK via in-app auth. Check this out http://blog.grio.com/2012/02/in-app-facebook-authentication-on-ios.html

Comment: Thank!, yes, that is one of the solutions. If I use FB-iOS-sdk I need to create an interface between native app and my internal webpages.